# Debian ошибка при запуске игры Alien-arena

Tags: debian

Установил на Debian 9 x64 игру alien-arena. Debian находится на VMware. 
Скачивал пакеты от сюда: https://pkgs.org/download/alien-arena
Выдаёт такие ошибки. Помогите разобраться почему не открывается X display
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по логу, ты запускаешь игру из-под сессии, в которой не запущен X11.
Следовательно, нужно либо делать `startx` перед запуском игры (чтобы стартовать x11 и инициализировать переменную окружения `DISPLAY`), либо проэкспортировать DISLPAY руками, в формате `способ_доступа:номер_сервера.номер_экрана` - если, конечно, знаешь путь до ближайшего сервера X11.

Подробнее с этим можно разобраться тут: http://heap.altlinux.org/modules/linux_intro/X11.html